# How to restore widget data to its previous state when reboot the phone?

Tags: java, android, widget, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I am setting widget data using **android:configure** tag which sets my **configuration activity** (i.e. it's list dialog ) which sets `onClick` event and image to my widget depending on user's selection. now the problem is whenever I reboot the phone or rerun my widget clears its image and clickListener to.

and even if I set a listener to BOOT_COMPLETED intent how I am going to reset widget's value to previous values as I **don't** want to call my configuration activity every time I reboot.

thanks in advance.!

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        AppUtils.showToast(context, " BOOT_COMPLETED ", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save your valuable data to `SQLite` `Room` `Realm` or whichever database tools you like, once you get the event after `BOOT_COMPLETED` restore the widget with values of your saved data

Comment: Yes. I can save data in SQLite or SharedPrefs too...But that's my last option.. i am looking more efficient way to do it like using appWidgetManager to reset widget but i couldn't find a way.... thanks for your reply.

Comment: I don't think there's no other way than this.

Answer (score 0):

The widget does **not provide** the ability to save its state after a reboot.

There is no other way here than to save it **yourself** in any of the persistent repositories.

Comment: This can be a comment and not an answer. Please, check the rules of this community.